# How to write RewriteRules and redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess

I want the site to run on https, for which i have written the http to https redirect rule as follows. however the other previous redirect stopped working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

#Rules for Versioned Static Files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.+)\.(.+)\.(css|js)$ $1/$2.$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^validate/(.*)/(.*)$ validate.php?email=$1&code=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

the css,js and validate redirect does not work when i add the https redirect above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://regex101.com/r/Za1JLg/1) can help you to correct your expressions and then write your RewriteRules, as you wish.

My guess is that, your might want to write something similar to:

```
(.*)(css|js)\/(.+)\.(css|js)
```

You can reduce the boundaries to see if it works. For example, you can drop the start `^` and end `$` chars, where possible, and simply use relative paths. You can for instance use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

instead of:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

and check.

---

#### CSS/JS

For CSS/JS URLs, you can reduce your boundaries maybe using an expression similar to:

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualize your expressions:

[image]

#### RewriteRule Test

[This link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) helps you to test your RewriteRules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)(css|js)\/(.+)\.(css|js) https://yourdomain/$2/$3.$4 [R=301]
```

which you can add to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
    RewriteRule (.*)(css|js)\/(.+)\.(css|js) https://yourdomain/$2/$3.$4 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

and continue and write for the other redirects that you wish.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help.. i fixed the issue by adding the rewrite condition that was missing above the https redirect.